# GIT repo in cPanel Home Directory

Tags: php, git

I'm trying to ensure that a GIT web hook I've written will still be usable for a site when the GIT repo itself is the user's home directory in a cPanel server.

In prior cases I've always had the repo in a directory below the home directory, which works fine since the pull/fetch is executed in that directory and not home.

Our hook is designed to allow for other developers to be able to upload files via ftp for testing and then once tested, committed to the given repo.  When we push the changes to our repo, the web hook accounts for the untracked or changed files and deletes them or checks them out so they can be updated via GIT.

This is part of the clients requirements and not negotiable, so I have to work around it.

Working on a dev version I can set up the file structure as so:

URL: http://dev.example.com

DIRS:

```
/home
   /username
      /dev
         /.git
         /.gitignore
         /application
         /public_html
```

No problems since /dev contains ONLY the files we're tracking and deploying.

But in a live environment, the directory structure looks like:

```
/home
   /.git
   /.gitignore
   /application
   /public_html
   ... 
   all other cpanel related user directories and files
```

My fetch function looks like so:

```
private function __fetch() {
    // change directory
    // set by searching recursively to find the .git directory
    // in this case $this->directory = home -- $this->alias = username
    chdir ($this->directory . '/' . $this->alias);

    // Fetch files for comparison
    exec("git fetch origin " . $this->branch . " 2>&1", $output);

    // Get local untracked files to delete
    exec("git status --porcelain -u | awk '/^[??]/ {print $2}'", $files);
    if (!empty($files)):
        foreach($files as $index => $file):
            unlink($this->directory . '/' . $this->alias . '/' . $file);
        endforeach;
    endif;
    unset($files);

    // Get local modified files to checkout
    exec("git diff --name-status | awk '/^[CDRMTUX]/ {print $2}'", $files);
    if (!empty($files)):
        foreach($files as $index => $file):
            exec("git checkout " . $file . " 2>&1", $error);
        endforeach;
    endif;
    unset($files);

    // We should be good now to merge
    exec("git pull origin " . $this->branch . " 2>&1", $result);

    return $result;
}
```

When listing untracked files in this directory, obviously there are tons which belong to cPanel, so ... the question is how can I rewrite this so that it can be executed successfully from this directory and not screw up anything belonging to cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I resolved this with some simple `.gitignore` changes.

My previous `.gitignore` looked like so:

```
.DS_Store

# Deploy
/public_html/deploy

# System Cache Files
/application/system/cache/*
!/application/system/cache/index.html

# Image File
/public_html/image/cache/*

# Modification Files
/application/vqmod/vqcache/*
/application/vqmod/logs/*

# Download Files
/application/system/download/*
!/application/system/download/index.html

# Log Files
/application/system/logs/*
!/application/system/logs/index.html
```

I added some additional ignores to the beginning to ignore all files, then negate the files we want to update like so:

```
.DS_Store
# Ignore all files and directories
*

# Except our actual application folders
!/.git
!/.gitignore
!/application
!/public_html

# Now negate whats needed
# Deploy
/public_html/deploy

# System Cache Files
/application/system/cache/*
!/application/system/cache/index.html

# Image File
/public_html/image/cache/*

# Modification Files
/application/vqmod/vqcache/*
/application/vqmod/logs/*

# Download Files
/application/system/download/*
!/application/system/download/index.html

# Log Files
/application/system/logs/*
!/application/system/logs/index.html
```

Seems to have worked as I'm getting correct updates as well as not getting all the cPanel files removed.

Hope this helps some other folks.